# Different font sizes of text for different layouts in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Is there any way to set different font sizes as defaults for different view layouts in Sublime Text 3?

Answer (score 2):

You can set different font sizes and names for different languages using syntax-specific [settings](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/settings.html). For example, say you want your HTML files to be in one font and size, your CSS files in another font and size, and all of the rest of your files in a third font and size. Your user preferences (`Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings`) may have this:

```js
"font_face": "Liberation Mono",
"font_size": 12
```

You could then set `Packages/User/HTML.sublime-settings` to include:

```js
"font_face": "Anonymous Pro",
"font_size": 14
```

and `Packages/User/CSS.sublime-settings` to include:

```js
"font_face": "Courier New",
"font_size": 16
```

The `Packages` directory is the one opened when selecting **`Preferences → Browse Packages…`**:

- Linux: `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages`
- OS X: `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages`
- Windows Regular Install: `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages`
- Windows Portable Install: `InstallationFolder\Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages`